# Cannot upload files to Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip, cloudinary

Cloudinary won't let me upload XLS files when it says they support it. I'm using the Heroku add-on.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\fortuneempire>rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.2)
irb(main):001:0> Cloudinary::Uploader.upload('C:\Users\Chloe\Documents\Chocolate_Store1.xls')
CloudinaryException: Invalid image file
        from C:/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/cloudinary-1.8.0/lib/cloudinary/uploader.rb:336:in `block in call_api'
```

http://cloudinary.com/faq

> Can I host any type of content on Cloudinary?
>   Yes. Cloudinary offers a complete image-management solution, but will manage any file type you throw at it, including videos, textual files and more. Cloudinary will serve such non-image files as-is. Do notice that you can not use Cloudinary to manage illegal or highly controversial content. If you're uncertain whether your files fall into this category, you may want to read our TOS and our CDN partner's Acceptable Use Policy.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add `:cloudinary_resource_type => :raw`.

```
  if Rails.env == 'production'
    has_attached_file :file, :storage => :cloudinary, :path => ':class/:id/:filename', 
      :cloudinary_resource_type => :raw
```

http://cloudinary.com/blog/using_cloudinary_to_manage_all_your_website_s_assets_in_the_cloud

https://github.com/GoGoCarl/paperclip-cloudinary#resource-types

Answer (score 0):

for javascript

```
let headers = new Headers({ name: "X-Requested-With", value: "XMLHttpRequest" });
let url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudinary_config.cloud_name}/image/upload`;
let form: FormData = new FormData();
form.append("upload_preset", cloudinary_config.upload_preset);
form.append("context", `photo=${this.title}`);
form.append("folder", window.location.hostname);
form.append("tags", "myphotoalbum");
form.append("file", file);

this.http.post(url, form).subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
    console.log("sonuc", data);
    this.success(data.toString());
    this.imageUrl.emit(JSON.stringify(data));
  },
  error => {
    this.warn("hata oluştu");
  },
  () => { // "sonuc"
  }

);
```