# How to set Cloudinary to accept all file types not just images

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, upload, cloudinary

I am trying to to configure Cloudinary to accept other file types as opposed to just images and video.
The files are small .gb (Gameboy rom files).
I have followed all of the Cloudinary guides as well as changing the resource_type to 'raw'.

I have emailed Cloudinary and will share the response when (and if) they get back to me.

Images upload fine, however I when I try to upload '.gb' it gives me the following error.

The documentation is not amazing and I was hoping that someone here had enough experience with cloudinary and know what the resource type should be for any file.

```
server.post('/publish',  upload.single('gamefile', { resource_type: "" }), (req, res, next) => {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(result) {
        console.log( result ); // logs outs { message: 'Invalid image file', http_code: 400 }
    });
```

Comment: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520572-Can-Cloudinary-be-used-for-types-of-files-other-than-images-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot upload files to Cloudinary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43989611/cannot-upload-files-to-cloudinary)

Comment: @JoshuaT That's for Ruby, though the idea is the same here.

Comment: I appreciate all the quick fire links, but I have read and tried all of these. Was hoping someone has actually had experience with this before.

Comment: That Cloudinary support link explains how to do what you want. (You need to use `resource_type: 'raw'`) If it did not work for you then please edit your question with exactly what you tried and what happened when you did so in order for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use version 2 of cloudinary:

```
server.post('/publish',  upload.single('gamefile'), (req, res, next) => {
      try{
         const result = await cloudinary.uploader.v2.upload(req.file.path, 
             {
                resource_type: "auto",
             }
         );
         return res.json(result);
      }
      catch(err){
         return res.json(err);
      }
);
```

or import version 2 of cloudinary:

```
const cloudinary = require ('cloudinary').v2;
```